# Cant find route, 404 any suggestions - C# .netcore

Tags: c#, routes, controller, http-status-code-404

Im trying to send the request to the route https://localhost:XXXX/Admins/products
Im getting 404 error, i have been trying with various combinations to solve this problem.
I cant find solution. Any help appreciated.

This is the controller file
[image]

```
    [Route("[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class AdminsController : Controller
        {
            private ApplicationDBContext _context;
    
            public AdminsController(ApplicationDBContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
            
    
            [HttpGet("products")]
            public IActionResult GetProizvodi() => Ok(new UzmiProizvodeAdmin(_context).GetProizvodi());
    
            [HttpGet("products/{id}")]
            public IActionResult GetProizvod(int id) => Ok(new UzmiProizvodAdmin(_context).GetProizvod(id));
    
            [HttpPost("products")]
            public IActionResult KreirajProizvod(ModeliView.Proizvodi pv) => Ok(new KreirajProizvod(_context).Save(pv));
    
            [HttpDelete("products/{id}")]
            public IActionResult ObrisiProizvod(int id) => Ok(new ObrisiProizvod(_context).Delete(id));
    
            [HttpPut("products")]
            public IActionResult AzurirajProizvod(ModeliView.Proizvodi pv) => Ok(new AzurirajProizvod(_context).Update(pv));
}}
```

This is the Program.cs file
[image]

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var configuration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: What does your Program.cs look like? Are you adding Endpoints to the pipeline? If you turn on Debug level logging (including Microsoft namespace), does it give you any hints?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: added since it has a lot of code i had to add an extra stupid text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `app.MapControllers();` in your `Program.cs`

```
app.MapRazorPages();
// You missed this one.
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image: Works as expected]